# What type of file of subtitles is this?

Tags: video, subtitle, formats, srt

Quick question, i know that this isnt .srt but i cant find which format is this, can anyone help with this markup?

Ps: they are portuguese.

```
0001 00:01:06:10 00:01:09:00

O crescimento da Internet mudou
as pequenas Startups para

0002 00:01:09:02 00:01:11:22

as empresas mais influentes
no mundo.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That looks like final cut pro subtitle, used for syncing the subtitles with the movie/clip example:

[Subtitle Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FQ6ab.gif)